# Why doesn't scikit-learn's LogisticRegression classifier use column-major for coefficients even when it is much faster?

Tags: performance, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, logistic-regression

I am using `LogisticRegression` for a classification problem with a large number of sparse features (tfidf vectors for documents to be specific) as well as a large number of classes. I noticed recently that performance seems to have dramatically worsened when upgrading to newer versions of scikit-learn. While it's hard to trace the exact origin of the performance problem, I did notice when profiling that `ravel` is called twice, which is taking up a large amount of the time at inference. What's interesting though, is that if I change the `coef_` matrix to column-major order with `np.asfortranarray`, I recover the performance I am expecting. I also noticed that the problem only occurs when the input is sparse, as it is in my case.

Is there a way to change inference so that it is fastest with row-major ordering? I suspect you couldn't do this without having to transpose the input matrix to `predict_proba`, which would be worse since now the time doing taken doing the raveling is unbounded. Or is there some flag to tell scikit to use column-major ordering in order to have to avoid these calls during inference?

Example code below:

```
import scipy
import numpy as np

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X = np.random.rand(10_000, 10_000)
y = np.random.randint(0, 500, size=10_000)
clf = LogisticRegression(max_iter=10).fit(X, y)

%timeit clf.predict_proba(scipy.sparse.rand(1, 10_000))
# 21.9 ms ± 973 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%prun
#   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
#        2    0.019    0.010    0.019    0.010 {method 'ravel' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
#        1    0.003    0.003    0.022    0.022 _compressed.py:493(_mul_multivector)

clf.coef_ = np.asfortranarray(clf.coef_)

%timeit clf.predict_proba(scipy.sparse.rand(1, 10_000))
# 467 µs ± 11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%prun clf.predict_proba(scipy.sparse.rand(1, 10_000))
#   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
#        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method scipy.sparse._sparsetools.csr_matvecs}
#        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'choice' of 'numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState' objects}
```

As you can see, converting the matrix to column-major order reduced the runtime of the ravel calls by a large margin.

Answer (score 0):

Sparse matmul is handled by scipy as `a.dot(b)`, and it needs `b` to be in row-major order. In this case, when you call `clf.predict_proba()` you're calculating `p @ clf.coef_.T`, and `clf.coef_.T` is done by switching between row-major and column-major order (cause doing it that way doesn't require a copy).

If `clf.coef_` is row-major order (which it will be after the model is fit), `clf.coef_.T` is column-major order and calling `clf.predict_proba()` requires it to be fully copied in memory (in this case, by `.ravel()`) to return it to row-major order.

When you turn `clf.coef_` to column-major order with `clf.coef_ = np.asfortranarray(clf.coef_)`, you make it so `clf.coef_.T` is row-major order, and `.ravel()` is basically a noop as it makes a view into the existing C array which doesn't have to be copied.

You have already found the most efficient workaround for this, so I don't know that there's anything else to be done. You could also just make `p` dense with `p.A`; the scipy.sparse matmul isn't terribly efficient and doesn't handle edge conditions well. This isn't a new thing and I don't know why you'd have not seen it with older sklearn.